# How to display files stored outside web application folder on same web server using a web application domain name URL in JSP and Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, documentviewer, google-document-viewer

I am working on a file sharing web application. This application is  being developed using jsp and servlet, MySql, Apache tomcat 6.0  webserver and Eclipse Juno IDE.  My expert level is beginner for these given technologies. This  application is a file sharing and trading application, where uploaded  files will be shown to the user in browser.

The types of files which will get uploaded will mostly pdf, image files  like jpg, jpeg, tiff, word, excel, powerpoint  etc.

This application have a file upload utility. Under this utility user enters some basic information regarding file in a HTML form and gives  path to file on local machine using browse button.  When User clicks on Submit button the data in form is saved in database and the file  gets uploaded on server on a certain common location specified by application.

**I have following questions and doubts regarding which I want guidance  and solution from experts.**

1) Currently I store the uploaded file on different location on same web server rather than storing it in web application folder to avoid  issues related to re-deployment of web application or up-gradation of server.
But the problem is, as I wish to make available the above mentioned file  to user in the browser in some sort of document viewer like scribed or google doc viewer etc. For this I  thought of using google document viewer service which I can use in the following way

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.xyz.com/pqr.pdf&embedded=true"> style="width:100%; height:600px;"></iframe>
```

But in above example as far as I know the pdf file mentioned in url  should be inside of web application folder. In my case my files are stored on a fix location but outside of web  application folder. **So I want to ask to experts that Is there any way to access the file situated outside of the web  application folder on same webserver with domain name of web application? How to achieve this and use it in above example?**

**My aim behind using multi document viewer like the one that is mentioned above is that I want to remove the dependancy of my application on local  machine applications and plugin.**

Please guide me in these issues friends!

Thanks You!

Comment: I would suggest splitting this in tree separate questions, because it is difficult to answer this way.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter Hello sir! I have splitted the question the seconde question url is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283205/how-to-use-google-document-viewer-offline-or-is-there-any-api-which-i-can-use-of

Comment: You need to create a servlet to stream the file to the client.

Comment: @Uooo Thank you sir for your reply But I dont understand what exactly you want to say? Please explain in detail. An example or a demo code or a reference link is welcome

Comment: @Uooo My question is I want to access the file which is situated outside of my web application directory like other files which are in web application directory using domain name followed by rest of the url. I dont want to download it.

Comment: Accessing files via http == downloading files ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"But in above example as far as I know the pdf file mentioned in url should be inside of web application folder."

No, that's not true. It can be anywhere, as long as it's downloadable by the document viewer web application, and as long as the document viewer web application accepts external URLs. If it doesn't accept external URLs, you will need to upload the files to the document viewer web application first.